# start-process: Setting current directory: No such file or directory

Tags: subprocess, timers

I have a timer which call a function itself calling `start-process`. Whenever the current buffer's directory changed (deleted/moved), I have the error

```lisp
start-process: Setting current directory: No such file or directory
```

The command ran by `start-process` is not directory specific, it can be run anywhere. So my workaround is setting `default-directory` to a directory which probably exists:

```lisp
(let ((default-directory user-emacs-directory))
  (start-process ...))
```

**Question.** Is that a common workaround to prevent `start-process` fail ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, that's the established technique. In my code I use `temporary-file-directory` instead, but this is just a detail.

Comment: Thank you, it's good to know!